# Visual Studio Code: Debugging of Jupyter Notebooks not working

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Unfortunately I am not able to debug Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code. Maybe somebody has an idea why?

Detailed description:

- After pressing "F5" the debugger (popup) starts as expected. Everything seems to run fine. "Only" that it doesn't stop at my breakpoints.
- Debugging normal (i.e. non-jupyter-notebook) python scripts works without problems.
- I have added the line '"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true,' to my 'settings.json'.
- I use the latest VScode version 1.60.2.
- There is only one python version installed on my laptop. Namely the latest anaconda distribution. I've also runned "conda update anaconda", "conda update python" and "pip install ipykernel". It shows that I use "ipykernel: 6.2.0".

[Running Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEtnY.png)

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#:~:text=in%20VS%20Code.-,debug%20a%20jupyter%20notebook

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But exporting to a plain python script is a very unsatisfying solution. Accord to several youtube Tutorials it should be possible. E.g.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2Yz4tivhPg

Answer (score 1):

Now it works for me. With pressing "F5" I get the above described wrong behavior. But with pressing "Debug Cell" next to the play button (or Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Enter) it works fine:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I discovered was to set a breakpoint on the first line of a code cell (even if it's just an import statement). This was hit and then can `F5` to the actual breakpoint.

Comment: ya, this worked for me, thanks